# How to generate font-size unit as em instead of rem in windicss?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, windicss

Using windicss with vuejs project, I found that its generating font-sizes as rem unit. e.g.

```
<div class="text-sm">Test</div>
```

generating css as

```
.text-sm {
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 1.25rem;
}
```

Is there any way to generate sizes as em? so `font-size: .875em`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a few ways (manually extending spacing to use `em` or creating a variant to apply to convert `rem` to `em`).

For the latter, you can check out this Tailwind GitHub issue.
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/3105

---

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/XFYT5WFump
(Not mine but in the github issue)

The usage of the plugin is

```css
em:text-sm
```

, which generates following output,

```css
.em\:text-sm {
    font-size: 0.875em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}
```

and the code for the plugin is,

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

/// https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/3105

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'light-blue': colors.lightBlue,
        cyan: colors.cyan,
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    fontSize: ({ after }) => after(['em']),
  },
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss/plugin')(function({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('em', ({ container }) => {
        container.walkRules(rule => {
          rule.selector = `.em\\:${rule.selector.slice(1)}`;
          rule.walkDecls((decl) => {
            decl.value = decl.value.replace('rem', 'em');
          });
        })
      })
    }),
  ],
}
```

---

I also created a similar ("unmaintained" for now) plugin a while ago,
https://github.com/downwindcss/variant-units

so if you want to support other units, you can check it out.

Comment: I usually set the margin, padding, radius, etc. based on the font size. So it's better to use `em` especially if the page is responsive and there are multiple elements. Otherwise one needs to adjust the margin, padding, etc. individually on each element. This is so annoying. With this, one can control the children's size by the parent's font size. It's very handy.